# Bijection from $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ to $H:=\{g\in G:g^2=e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ be a group. Construct a bijection from $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ to $H:=\{g\in G:g^2=e\},$ where $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ stands for the set of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to $G.$

*Attempt.* Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_2\to G$ a group homomorphism and we would like to map $f$
to an element $g$ of $G$ such that $g^2=e$ in a way such that the map is one to one and onto. The elements we have are $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ (here: $0$=set of even integers, $1$=set of odd integers), so a choice would be $f\mapsto f(0)$ (indeed, $f(0)^2=f(0^2)=f(0)=e$, since $f$ is  homomorphism). But if $f(0)=h(0)$ for homomorphisms $f,\,h$, then I don't see how $f=h$ (also, if $g^2=e$, how do we get a homomorphism $f$ such that $f(0)=g$?). Maybe another map would do the work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try $f(1)$.....

Comment: Indeed, $f(1)^2=f(1+1)=f(0)=e$. But if $f(1)=h(1),$ why $f(0)=h(0)$? Also, if $g\in G$ such that $g^2=e$, why $f(1)=g$ for some homomorphism $f$?

Comment: You proved that $f(0) = e$ for all homomorphisms $f$. For your second question, try defining a homomorphism so that $f(1) = g$, and $f(0) =...$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to gather all comments and your attempt to an answer just for completion.

Let $W:Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)\to H=\{g\in G| \ g^2=e\}$ with $W(f)=f(1)$. Then:

- $W$ is well defined: it is $f(1)\in H$ since $f^2(1)=f(1+1)=f(0)=e$.
- $W$ is $1-1$: Let $f(1)=g(1)$ for some $f,g\in Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$. Then since $f(0)=g(0)$ for all $f,g\in Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ it is $f=g$.
- $W$ is onto: Let $g\in G$ s.t. $g^2=e$. We define $f\in Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ with $f(0)=e$ and $f(1)=g$. Then $f$ is indeed in $ Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2,G)$ and $W(f)=f(1)=g$.$\checkmark$

Comment: Ι was just about to answer it myself! Thank you Γιάννη.

Comment: I suggest changing the notation a bit, because using $H$ for the map and for the subset of $G$ might be confusing.